# JDK 1.8 JavaFX Tab Pane Throwing NullPointerException

Tags: tabs, nullpointerexception, javafx

I want to preface this question by stating that the following code works perfectly fine in JDK 1.7. The goal here is to create a tab pane with a tab at the end (with text set to "+") so that whenever this tab is selected, the program creates a new tab in the tab pane. This functionality works fine. The problem is that when you close the New Tab via the X, it switches to the "Add Tab," creates a new tab, then throws the following NullPointerException in some JDK code (and the app now shows TWO new tabs which are the same exact object):

Executing C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestJavaFx\dist\run2082574567\TestJavaFx.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre/bin/java
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin.access$302(TabPaneSkin.java:1040)
....

I have cut down the trouble code to bare minimums to display the issue, and it is as follows:

```
public class TestTabApp extends Application {

    private TabPane tabPane;
    private Tab addTab;
    private Tab currentTab;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //Create the tab pane and the 'addTab' for adding new tabs.
        tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB);

        addTab = new Tab("+");
        addTab.setClosable(false);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(addTab);

        //Add a listener to listen for changes to tab selection.
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldSelectedTab, Tab newSelectedTab) {

                //If we change to the addTab create a
                //new tab and change selection.
                if (newSelectedTab == addTab) {
                    //Create the new tab.
                    createNewTab();
                } else {
                    currentTab = newSelectedTab;
                }
            }
        });
        //Create a new tab for initial load of the app
        createNewTab();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tabPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Tab Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Tab createNewTab() {
        Tab newTab = new Tab("New Tab");
        newTab.setClosable(true);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tabPane.getTabs().size() - 1, newTab);
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(newTab);
        return newTab;
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is happening now in JDK 1.8, but not in 1.7? Is there a bug in 1.8?

Answer (score 2):

I also posted this on the Oracle forums and received a response from a David Grieve:

This is clearly a bug in the TabPaneSkin code. What seems to be happening is that the tab is removed before the tab removal animation completes. The problem may be exacerbated by the code automatically adding a tab if the last tab is removed, but the core code shouldn't fall over like that.

As a workaround, turn the tab close animation off with the following bit of CSS.

```
tabPane.setStyle("-fx-close-tab-animation: none;");
```

I have created https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36443 to track the issue.

Comment: Caveat: the issue is marked as resolved in 8u20, but I see the same (or a similar) issue in 8u25 if I `clear()` the tabs and then set the tabs *too soon* with `setAll()`, or add too many tabs in a row with `add()`.  In both cases, disabling the close-tab animation cures the problem.